# What to use to set styling dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, ng-class, ng-style

I started working with angular and creating my "little" project. I came up to templating issue.

Basically, I try to set colour for elements dynamically with angular. I can't figure out what would be the best and the "right" way to do it.

Is it ok to use if statements in scope? Or better use directive?

My main goal is to be able to set colors from admin mode to toolbar and their icons.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: I am asking which way is better to go with.

Comment: I would suggest you to go with ng-class, you don't need to anything in your controller and stuff with that so the code will be cleaner. I am sorry for not reading your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

You can use ngClass with any expression.

If what you are after is coloring odd/even rows of a table, you could also use

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven

Answer (score 0):

An example of ng-class

```
      <div ng-class="{'a-class': !if.someObjects.variable.negativeReponse,
                      'b-class': some.methodsResponse()
                      }" >
```